# Dual password authentication

Tags: php, security, authentication, passwords

I decided to start with a dual password authentication in a recent project.
Login details are: email, password, secret.

Password (min. 8 chr) and secret (min. 6 chr) are the two passwords.

In order to make it as difficult as possible to hack them I thought I should encrypt the username using openssl and use the two passwords as encryption key and initialization vector.

```php
openssl_encrypt($email, 'aes-256-cbc', $password, false, $secret)
```

Is this secure or have I just came up with a bad idea?

Comment: take a look `password_hash` , its a one way hash, http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: that requires I store the password. My idea was to not store the passwords, just the encrypted username based on them

Comment: What makes you think two passwords are better than one? That is not two factor authentication which generally means two of: something you know (ex: password), something you have (ex: RSA fob) or something you are (ex: finger print).

Comment: My SME mentions that dual passwords are more secure but only if you have dual custody.

Comment: Yes, dual custody grows security by a high factor, but still even without dual custody you still force users to provide more characters and thus increase the strengths. An 8 character password is less secure than two of 8 characters. That makes building rainbow tables very difficult.

Comment: So just require more characters. But this is a good way to confuse users since they are not familiar with the concept of two passwords: "make it as difficult as possible" for them. Suggestion: study the current best practice literature.

Comment: Actually most financial systems today require a password and a secret to gain access and a token on top for some.

Comment: Your idea is the same as having ONE password which is the concatenation of `length_of_password + ":" + password + secret`. This unique password would be splitted on the first occurrence of the separator ":", then splitted again according to the length, making it suitable for your operation. So, just simplify the life of the user and just ask for a 14 chr min password.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this secure or have I just came up with a bad idea?

You are [rolling your own crypto](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/75204435608/write-crypto-code-dont-publish-it), so in that sense it *is* a bad idea.

As for security: `openssl_encrypt()` expects the `$password` parameter to be a cryptography key, not a human-readable password. Similarly, the IV should be a random per-message string. Using human readable values for both inputs is dangerous. (Specifically, you're more susceptible to brute force.)

It sounds like you want to use [`password_hash()`](https://secure.php.net/password_hash) + [`password_verify()`](https://secure.php.net/password_verify) and then integrate with a two factor authentication solution (e.g. [Yubikey](https://github.com/bitbeans/Yubikey), Google Authenticator) for your "secret" field.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to save some kind of information in your database.  What you're doing is very similar to what is primarily done and what Andrew posted above.  The general way that passwords are securely hashed is to generate some kind of unique salt for each user, in your case you've decided to do this based on a secret, but you can just as securely use some kind of randomized information.

You then hash this password by using this salt, and save both the salt and the hashed password in your database.  When a user enters a password to validate, you simply hash it with that user's salt, and if it matches the hashed value then they have successfully authenticated, however because of the way you have hashed the passwords it makes it difficult for someone who gains access to your database to reverse this process as they'd need to individually crack each password (or do something with rainbow tables/etc).

What you've posted is a version of the above standard.

Comment: *"You then hash this password by using this salt"* - If that's a reference to `password_hash()`, additional salting has been removed from PHP 7.0 and is recommended not to create their own salt.

Comment: I'm referring to the process of generating a secure hash in general, as opposed to specifically the password_hash function.  Thanks for the point though!

Comment: So I take it my method is just as safe?

Comment: I do not save the password not the salt in  the database. I only save the encrypted email based on the password and secret.